# Physics(2D) module is not present. This PhysicsRaycaster(2d) will have no effect. (Unity 2020.1.0a14)

Tags: unity-game-engine

[image: Problem picture]

I am trying to capture Unity's ***OnMouseDown*** events.
As far as I concerned, I need to add Physics Raycaster module into my Main Camera object.
But, when I tried to do so, there was a message "Physics module is not present. This Raycaster will have no effect". The same with 2D.

I have already tried:

- Reset packages to default
- Find Physics\Physics2D in asset store

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this issue?

Comment: Physics2D is the 2D physics engine that comes with Unity. If you are not making a 2D game and have not created your project with the 2D physics engine, you want to use `Physics` instead.

Comment: @Draco18s, I created my project as a 2D game, maybe I have forgotten to add the 2D physics engine. But, I do not have both Physics 2D and Physics modules.

Comment: I am having the exact same issue with unity 2019.3.0f1 with OnMouseDown working in the editor but not on device and "physics module is not present" warning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have rolled back the unity editor's version to 2019.2.14f1 and this solved my problem.

Comment: Given that the version of 2020.1 you attempted to use, it may be worth filing a bug report with Unity.

Answer (score 0):

I have investigated the issue and it seems to be only an editor script problem. The warning is there, but the raycaster works fine.